# Problema com json slim framework

Tags: php, json, slim, slimframework, slimframwork

Estou fazendo uma api para fazer a integração de dois sistemas diferentes, o sistema me manda o seguinte json:

```
cJson = [{"TESTE": "1"}]
```

fiquei 3 dias com um problema pois não estava conseguindo pegar o json que o outro sistema me mandava via post com nenhum desses dois métodos abaixo:

```
$dados = $request->getBody();

$dados = $request->getParsedBody();
```

Resolvi esse problema e agora consigo pegar o json que o outro sistema me envia com o seginte método:

```
$dados = (string) $resquest->getBody();
```

Porém esse método logo acima me retorna uma string, e eu preciso transforma-lo em array ou em objeto para inseri-lo no banco de dados. quando dou um echo o que é retornado para mim é justamente o que eu quero veja logo abaixo:

```
echo $dados; 
resultado:   [{"TESTE": "1"}]
```

Mas quando uso um json_decode ele não me retorna nada retorna null, exemplo:

```
echo json_decode($dados);
resultado: null
```

Seria pelo fator de ser uma string ?
Teria algum jeito de eu resolver isso ?
Já tenho o dado mas não consigo manipula-lo para inserir no banco...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não há nada errado com a conversão da string para JSON. O problema é que não dá para exibir o resultado com **echo( )**, porque o retorno da função **json_decode( )** é um array.

Experimente com **print_r( )**:

```
print_r(json_decode('[{"TESTE": "1"}]'));
resultado: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [TESTE] => 1 ) )
```

Comment: Não sei porque mas usei assim: json_decode($dados, true); ai deu certo.

Answer (score 0):

Para transformar de um objeto json para um array no Php você deve utilizar a sintaxe:
 
[`echo json_decode($dados, TRUE);`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php) . 
 
Você tem que passar o parâmetro TRUE para ele transformar em array.

Para imprimir as informações você deve efetuar um foreach para acessar os valores e aí poderá utilizar echo, se estiver tentando imprimir direto o array deve utilizar o comando [print_r](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.print-r.php).